# Check whether break condition was triggered

Tags: python, loops, break, sentinel

Is there an elegant way in Python to detect whether a break condition was engaged at the **last** iteration or **never** at all?

C++ example:

```
int k, n = 10;
for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    if (condition) break;

if (k == n) cout << "Never broke\n";
else        cout << "Broke at " << k << '\n';
```

Python example:

```
n = 10
for k in range(n):
    if condition: break

if k == n: print("Never broke")
else:      print("Broke at", k)
```

In Python, we don't know whether `condition` was true at the last iteration since k is 9 in both cases.

Why not just use `range(n + 1)` instead? Because on some contexts, we might get an "index out of range" error when k is n.

One possible workaround is to use a sentinel value as shown below, but is there a better way?

```
n, flag = 10, True
for k in range(n):
    if condition:
        flag = False
        break

if flag: print("Never broke")
else:    print("Broke at", k)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `for`/`else`. That's specifically what it's for.

```
for k in range(n):
    if condition:
       print("Broke at", k)
       break
else:
    print("Never broke")
```

Comment: I always describe `for`/`else` as being for the needle in a haystack case: If you find the needle, you `break`, and if there was no needle, the `else` case is what tells you the haystack is nothing but hay.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily better, but often you can condense the loop into a use of `any` or  `all` (for when you only care if a value was found) or `next` (for when you care about the value found).

For example, to find the first item satisfying some test, or `None` if no such item exists, you can use two-arg `next` plus a generator expression:

```
needle = next((x for x in haystack if isneedle(x)), None)
if needle is not None:
    ... do stuff with needle ...
else:
    ... no needle ...
```

or roughly equivalently with one-arg `next` and exception handling:

```
try:
    needle = next(x for x in haystack if isneedle(x))
except StopIteration:
    ... no needle ...
else:
    ... do stuff with needle ...
```

A realistic use case might be identifying a prime number via trial division. In that case, you don't care what factor you found, you just care that there was a factor, so you could write a testing function as:

```
num = ...
isnumprime = num >= 2 and all(num % f != 0 for f in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1))
```

`for`/`else` is a perfectly adequate way to do this (see other answers), but `any`/`all`/`next` (usually with generator expressions) can be cleaner in specific contexts.